# Proving an identity regarding Levi-civita connections of a metric

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

[image]

Here $\nabla$ is the levi-civita connection of the given metric $g$. I am stuck at the last equality (g). What on earth does $\nabla^a \nabla_a$ mean? Isn't it just $g^{ab}\nabla_a \nabla_b$? But, then the equality does not hold because the left side of (g) is just $g^{ab}\partial_a\partial_bf$ and the right side of (g) contains more than that. Could anyone please help me what $\nabla^a \nabla_a$ mean?

Comment: Why do you think the right side contains more?

Answer (score 1):

You are right for the first statement, i.e.,
$$
\nabla^a\nabla_af=g^{ab}\nabla_a\nabla_bf.
$$
However, your second statement remains to be improved. Provided that
$$
\nabla_bf=\partial_bf
$$
is a vector,
$$
\nabla_a\nabla_bf=\nabla_a\left(\partial_bf\right)=\partial_a\left(\partial_bf\right)-\Gamma_{ab}^c\left(\partial_cf\right).
$$
Therefore,
$$
\nabla^a\nabla_af=g^{ab}\nabla_a\nabla_bf=g^{ab}\left(\partial_a\partial_bf-\Gamma_{ab}^c\partial_cf\right).
$$
This is still faraway from the ultimate goal. To make it short, we could turn to part (e) for help.

Provided that, using $\nabla_ag^{bc}=0$,
$$
\nabla^a\nabla_af=g^{ab}\nabla_a\nabla_bf=\nabla_a\left(g^{ab}\nabla_bf\right)=\nabla_a\left(g^{ab}\partial_bf\right)
$$
and that, from part (e),
$$
\nabla_aV^a=\left|g\right|^{-1/2}\partial_a\left(\left|g\right|^{1/2}V^a\right),
$$
let $V^a=g^{ab}\partial_bf$, and the last formula immediately gives
$$
\nabla^a\nabla_af=\nabla_a\left(g^{ab}\partial_bf\right)=\left|g\right|^{-1/2}\partial_a\left(\left|g\right|^{1/2}g^{ab}\partial_bf\right),
$$
as is expected.

Comment: As far as I know, $\nabla_a f$ is a directional derivative, which is a scalar. Why is it a vector?

Comment: @Keith: Yes, but $a$ could be $1$, $2$, ..., $n$ with $n$ the dimension of your manifold. Therefore, each $\nabla_af$ serves as a component of the same vector.

Comment: @Keith: If you follow a physics track, you may see that $\nabla_af$ would transform under the coordinate transformation (if it is a scalar, it does not transform under any coordinate transformation). If you follow a differential geometry track, you may see that $\nabla_af$ is a vector in the cotangent space of the manifold, whose complete form reads $\nabla_af{\rm d}x^a$, where $\left\{{\rm d}x^a\right\}_a$ is a basis for the cotangent space.

Comment: And what is the relation between the metric and the Christoffel symbol you are saying? I cannot proceed at all....

Comment: @Keith: I just updated my answer with a complete proof therein, using part (e) in your script. There I adopted one more result $\nabla_ag^{bc}=0$, i.e., $\partial_ag^{bc}-\Gamma_{ad}^bg^{dc}-\Gamma_{ad}^cg^{bd}=0$. This is because covariant derivative preserves the metric tensor, namely both $g_{bc}$ and $g^{bc}$ appear as constants when $\nabla_a$ acts on them.